# Responsive Menu utilizing images

Tags: html, css

The menu I am trying to create is:

[image: navigation]

The menu is in Chinese & English. The problem is @font-face isn't practical with Chinese characters as each font is over 5mb. So - I would need to resort to images.

So - my ideas are:

- Are there any image replacement techniques that scale?
- How can you extract the characters out of the font to make a custom font face?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: Have you tried cufon? http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ They claims that chinese font will be below 100k. And you have an option to pick only the characters that you need.

Comment: @vojtek - please post as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cufon - http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

It renders the text image automatically in Javascript and is also readable for search engines.

Comment: I just tried cufon - and yes it works with Chinese Character. My only issue is I am trying to be responsive - and cufon only works on page refresh.

Comment: Let me do some experimentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "being responsive"?

Comment: The heading will resize to fit different devices (ipad, mobile, browser)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Cufon does not work only on page refresh. It renders the fonts automatically on each call of Cufon.replace - if that helps you.